# Right way to have a scrollable bottom view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

What is the right way to have a scrollable bottom view?

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/wrnTextP1"
        android:text="Ok , batatas  "/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        style="@style/FullWidthButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Chega por hoje!" />
</LinearLayout>
```

at the preview its looke fine, but when I run it on the emulator the view(in this case: the button) its not at bottom at all.

[image]

Comment: which view are you talking about?

Comment: The button... I was thiking those images was self explanatory

Comment: Should this bottom button be scrollable or just be at the bottom and content above is scrollable?

Comment: You need to use  ` android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` with `RelativeLayout` mostly not with `LinearLayout`. For that you can use `layout_gravity="bottom". But in your case `ScrollView` does not make any sense. If you want to have a `ScrollView` and put a button fixed to the bottom use `RelativeLayout` as root layout and add the button to the relative layout, set the `alignParentBottom="true"` and add the `ScrollView` as a child to the root `RelativeLayout`

Comment: @ArturSzymański this button should be scrollable

Comment: There's an extra view (the speech bubble) in your emulator screnshot; did you omit any code from your layout?

Comment: @BenP This is instabug icon, its not part of the layout

Comment: post your styles xml code seems fine

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding how `ScrollView` is meant to be used. The `LinearLayout` child of your ScrollView has a `match_parent` height... if your ScrollView is the same height as the screen, and the LinearLayout is the same height as the ScrollView, then there's nothing to scroll (all the content is the size of the screen).

The direct child of a `ScrollView` should either have a fixed height (like `2000dp`) or use `wrap_content`.

If you use a fixed height, then the rest of your code "works"; you can have a `Space` element that uses `layout_weight` to push the last view down to the bottom of your LinearLayout. However, if you're using `wrap_content`, this is impossible (since there's no "extra" space for the `layout_weight` to consume).

Instead, you could consider putting the "bottom" view *outside* of the `ScrollView`. Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        ...

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        style="@style/FullWidthButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Chega por hoje!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Nice explanation but I'm using scrollview with fillViewPort="true" that should stretch the content anyway. And the button should be at the very bottom when has no scroll available or scroll as well